# Scan an array using strcmp

Tags: c, cstring, strcmp

I'm wondering if there's a way you can scan an array for a match using `strcmp`. I know the parameters passed to `strcmp` are C strings. So something like this wouldn't work:

```
strcmp(arrayofstrings[x], c-string)
```

Comment: So what is `string` and `string2`?

Comment: arrayofstrings is a array of cstrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to search the entire array, rather than just comparing two elements, you will need a loop.

```
const int N = 10;
const char * desired = "desiredString";
char * arrayOfStrings[N];

// You should initialize the elements
// in arrayOfStrings[] before searching

// Searching an unsorted array is O(N)
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(arrayOfStrings[i], desired) == 0)
    {
        printf("Found %s.", desired);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what if string1 is not a const, its constantly be overwritten by a new string of data

Comment: nevermind, i just misunderstood the code you wrote i get it now thanks

Answer (score 1):

It would work as long as the arguments can be reduced to of type `const char*`.

```
char *a[] = { "Hello", "Hello" };  // Array of pointers to c strings
if ( !strcmp(a[0],a[1]) ){
    // true in this case
}
```

Comment: so how would i make this work if uni is a char of 100 elements and string1 is 16? if (!strcmp(uni[i],string1)

Comment: `uni[i]` is of type **char** and not **char***. They can not be compared.

Comment: That would be clumsy way of doing it. And I cann't think any other way of doing though. BTW, why do you wish to compare string with a char any way.

Comment: Both the strings being compared **must** be null terminated. I amn't sure how **char** is going to be null terminated in this case.